# I need a way to submit an email to a database or text file and also goto a link with one click

Tags: jquery

I am working on an employment agencies website and they want me to add a feature that someone will enter their email address and when they click to submit it, it place it into a text file for storage and then redirects them to the application page.

this is what i got but its not working

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
  var cur = $(this).attr('href')
  $(this).attr('href',cur + '&email=' + escape($('#email').val()))
})
```

Comment: what part is not working?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845519/i-need-a-method-to-both-submit-an-email-address-to-a-database-and-redirect-to-a

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to the link:

```
window.open('your link')
```

Example:

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr('href')
  var newHref = href + '&email=' + escape($('#email').val())

  // you only need ONE of these next two lines....
  window.open(newHref); // this would open in a new window/tab
  document.location = newHref; // this would redirect the current page to the new link

  e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the link from working with the wrong href
})
```

Comment: ok ill try it, i will be first to admit that I suck with code.

Comment: also, what would i need to add to get the email address appended to a text file? i just want it to be super simple for now as I am just testing this method out

Comment: You'd have to do that on the server-side with say PHP

Comment: yeah i figured id have to use php or something, i have some mailchimp code that i would like to use but i dont know what id need to do to get it working with this

Comment: update your question with the server-side code you currently have

Comment: i had to put it on pastebim cuz its too long to post on here, is the link showing up?

Comment: yes, its just a bit superfluous. I would suggest you look into creating your own simplified script to save the email. What your trying to accomplish is relatively easy and doesn't require all that code.

Comment: okay i found some code that is WAYYYYYY less complex than that last one. here it is on pastebin http://pastebin.com/gmnW99sC  where would i put that code you wrote to get this thing working? i can paypal ya some money or something if ya want

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.  You would need to make an ajax call to a server-side page and save the email address, then redirect the user to the desired page.

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $('#email').val(),
        href = $(this).attr('href'),
        newHref = href + '&email=' + escape(email);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/SaveEmail',
        data: {'email': email},
        success: function() {
            // email saved successfully
            window.location = newHref;
        },
        error: function() {
            // server error while saving email
            alert('Error occurred!')
        }
    })
});
```